# How to reflect the semantic web benefits in Enterprise Information System?

Tags: semantic-web

I am developing a demo of semantic web-based Information System, which just uses SPARQL instead of traditional SQL to manipulate dataset. How the application can demonstrate Semantic Web benefits.

I did steps as below:

1. The client gets parameters from web UI.
2. Requests a web service.
3. The service generates a SPARQL command according to given parameters.
4. The service uses Jena/SDB API to execute the SPARQL command.
5. Retrieves or persists data from or to MySQL.
6. Parsing returned result set.
7. Responses a JSON object to the client.
8. The client uses Javascript + html to display data.

Currently, the application just has CRUD operations. Only one difference to the traditional IS, which is using SPARQL instead of SQL. It seems that cannot see obviously semantic features. I'm just thinking of two points:

1. To demonstrate data federating through SPARQL. From this point, can I imagine that the system can be broken down into several subsystem and work on their independent dataset but they can communicate with each other by SPARQL, which because they work on the RDF specification.
2. Reasoning over datasets. I use Ontologies to describe data schema, should my reasoning operation need to based on them. In my application, I try to get a RDF model, and use Pellet to do inferences. Is that corrent way?

Basically, if the application can demostrate data federating and reasoning, which can be seen as a semantic web-based application. Do I understand it right?

Hopefully, the application can combine services together automatically through semantic description. Furthermore, any other third party data sources may be communicate with the system and work immediately.

Comment: After lots of reading, a basic understanding emerged. It seems that reasoning is one of main features of semantic webs. For traditional application, business logic were wrote into codes directly by if-else. For semantic web-based application, the logic can be explicit, which means describe logic relations in Ontologies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ,you are right.the benefit with semantic web being you can write separate set of ontologies which will describe the domains(e.g. product,user) and then combine them using inference ,reasoning and make the data seem much more useful(r.g. product types and user preferences).
The difference being the rules for the data are now written with the data and not in the business logic layer.
Hope this helps .:)